# Why can't get UIView.frame property with class_getProperty?

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, xctest

It always return a NULL instead of the property.

```
objc_property_t property = class_getProperty([UIView class], "frame");
XCTAssertTrue(property != NULL,
              @"UIView.frame property should be here.");
```

Works fine with `center` for example, but with `frame` seems not.

Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa, seems it does not have such property indeed, but a method. Documentation shows as a property, but in reality it is a method. https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS7-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIView.h

Weird.